# Resteasy to set form url encoded x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, url-encoding

I'm working with `Resteasy 2.2.1.GA`, I have to call some services. 
If I call a service with `body` method and if request message contains a `&` the service responds with an error. I tried to set `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, but the solution doesn't works. 
If I call the service with another client, for example with `Postman` (Chrome plugin), the service responds successfully.

How I can set `x-www-form-urlencoded` like postman plugin? 
Below my code:

```
> ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(url);
> request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
> request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
> request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE ,jsonRequest); 
> response = request.post(String.class);
> String jsonResponse = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved using the url encoder of message:

```
request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE ,URLEncoder.encode(jsonResponse,"UTF-8"));
```

Thanks, bye.